# Structural Equation Modeling (SEM) with betareg in R

Tags: r, regression, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, beta-regression

We have an SEM model and we were using [Lavaan](https://lavaan.ugent.be/) but we learned that the distribution of the residuals of one of the regressions is far from normal. The response variable in that equation is students' exam grades and if we transfer them to range (0, 1) it well-fits a beta distribution.
I'd appreciate it if you let us know how we can use `betareg` for one of our regressions or somehow indicate that the distribution of the response variable is Beta in an SEM model in R. Also, an example code snippet will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fit an SEM model with beta distributed residuals, I guess your best bet is to use Stan and program your model in a Bayesian framework.